# Data-structure for concurent heavy read workload

Tags: algorithm, go, data-structures, containers

I am looking for a data-structure that stores 32bytes strings and allows fast lookups with preferred O(1) or O(log N) lookup complexity (the goal is only to determine if the key exists). Removal and insertion complexity is not critical, since those operations will be infrequent.

Not that it is relevant to the question, but i am working in Go. I could use a *hashmap* backed by a mutex, but contention would be a problem, and I prefer to avoid sharding if there is a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Have you benchmarked a `map[string]struct{}` with an [`RWMutex`](https://godoc.org/sync#RWMutex)?

Comment: [This hasmap package](https://github.com/cornelk/hashmap) could fit your needs.

Comment: How many lookups per second are we talking here? How many total keys? You say that removal and insertion are infrequent. How infrequent? It sounds to me like a hashmap and a reader/writer lock will be very effective for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148809/how-to-use-rwmutex-in-golang

Answer (score 0):

`map` is safe for concurrent read. You could put your desired map inside a `sync/atomic.Value` and when you want to write to it, duplicate the map and change it, then put it back inside `Value`. From [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value):

> The following example shows how to maintain a scalable frequently
>   read, but infrequently updated data structure using copy-on-write
>   idiom.
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> type Map map[string]string
> var m Value
> m.Store(make(Map))
> var mu sync.Mutex // used only by writers
> // read function can be used to read the data without further synchronization
> read := func(key string) (val string) {
>         m1 := m.Load().(Map)
>         return m1[key]
> }
> // insert function can be used to update the data without further synchronization
> insert := func(key, val string) {
>         mu.Lock() // synchronize with other potential writers
>         defer mu.Unlock()
>         m1 := m.Load().(Map) // load current value of the data structure
>         m2 := make(Map)      // create a new value
>         for k, v := range m1 {
>                 m2[k] = v // copy all data from the current object to the new one
>         }
>         m2[key] = val // do the update that we need
>         m.Store(m2)   // atomically replace the current object with the new one
>         // At this point all new readers start working with the new version.
>         // The old version will be garbage collected once the existing readers
>         // (if any) are done with it.
> }
> _, _ = read, insert
> ```

You could also use a pointer to you `map` instead of `Value` and store it atomically using [StorePointer/LoadPointer](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#StorePointer) but that's not cleaner cause you should use an unsafe pointer and cast it.